# How to validate Bootstrap editor using java script

Tags: javascript

How to validate Bootstrap editor using java script. I have tried the below code but its not working.

```
if ( $("#Editor-editor").html() == "" )
{
 alert("Should not empty");
}
```

If bootstrap editor is empty then then alert message should show.

Answer (score 0):

Editor=input ?
On validation you have to work with custom library.
For instance

1. jquery validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/

   2. io validation http://formvalidation.io

These validations rendered different ways so first you need to choose one js library.

After you included your library , checking empty elements is performed automatically, depending on attributes of element. For instance:
`<input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>`
means you need to fill this field with minlength=2.